# Type 'IntentHandler' does not conform to protocol 'INStartAudioCallIntentHandling'

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode8, ios-app-extension

I’m using INStartAudioCallIntentHandling in swift 2.3 and I’m getting this error :

```
Type ‘IntentHandler’ does not conform to protocol ‘INStartAudioCallIntentHandling’
```

I’m using Xcode 8.2.1. I put the `func handle(startAudioCall intent: INStartAudioCallIntent, completion: (INStartAudioCallIntentResponse) -> Void)` method  into the class.Why i'm getting this error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably also add

```
func confirm(start​Audio​Call:​ INStart​Audio​Call​Intent, completion:​ (INStart​Audio​Call​Intent​Response) -> Void)
```

and

```
func resolve​Contacts(for​Start​Audio​Call:​ INStart​Audio​Call​Intent, with:​ ([INPerson​Resolution​Result]) -> Void)
```

> Use the methods of the INStart​Audio​Call​Intent​Handling protocol to
>   resolve, confirm, and handle requests to start an audio-only call with
>   the designated users. Adopt this protocol in an object of your Intents
>   extension that is capable of validating the call information.

[source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents/instartaudiocallintenthandling)

Comment: They both are optional, did not help.

Comment: @EternalLight checked this? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62250

Comment: Yes, currently reading. They say the problem is with @escaping attribute in Swift 3. Closures are escaping by default in Swift 2.3 and it should just work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.1 solution.**

We're passing in that user activity with Info that comes from the contacts display name. I'm going to need to say who I'm going to call.

I have this simple array that is a representation of a mock database. Maybe in your application have some kind of list of users that has all their contact information and you can check those contacts against the information that was passed into resolveContacts. The user says they want to call Dave, I make sure that that's in the database and if it is, then I call Dave. And in order to make the call, you need an INPerson, which requires a personHandle, which is basically a unique identifier for a human being.

You can either use an email or a phone number. I've chosen to go with a phone number right here. If it has the appropriate name, it creates this INPersonHandle, passes it in as a person with this phone number and whatever name, if it matches my existing contacts and then I say that the completion is successful with that person. If there is no matching contact, then we refer back to the user saying that we need a value.

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension,INStartAudioCallIntentHandling {
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any? {
        return self
    }
    func handle(startAudioCall intent: INStartAudioCallIntent, completion: @escaping (INStartAudioCallIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        print("handle")
        let ua = NSUserActivity(activityType: "Call")
        let person:String = intent.contacts![0].displayName
        ua.userInfo = ["person":person]
        completion(INStartAudioCallIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: ua))
    }

    func confirm(startAudioCall intent: INStartAudioCallIntent, completion: @escaping (INStartAudioCallIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        completion(INStartAudioCallIntentResponse(code: .ready, userActivity: nil))
    }

    func resolveContacts(forStartAudioCall intent: INStartAudioCallIntent, with completion: @escaping ([INPersonResolutionResult]) -> Void) {
        print("resolveContacts")
        let contacts:[String] = ["Dave","James","Herman"]
        for contact in contacts {
            if intent.contacts?[0].spokenPhrase?.uppercased() == contact.uppercased() {
                let personHandle:INPersonHandle = INPersonHandle(value: "1-555-555-5555", type: .phoneNumber)
                let person:INPerson = INPerson(personHandle: personHandle, nameComponents: nil, displayName: contact, image: nil, contactIdentifier: nil, customIdentifier: nil)
                completion([INPersonResolutionResult.success(with: person)])
                return
            }
        }
        completion([INPersonResolutionResult.needsValue()])
    }

}
```